# Calendário em Angular 4

Tags: angularjs, calendar

estou com um problema... preciso que em minha aplicação tenha um calendário, bem simples. Eu consegui achar apenas aqueles que precisam de um input, como o exemplo abaixo.

```
<input class="teste">
```

e

```
$('.teste').pickadate({});
```

Mas no caso preciso que fiquei aberto direito em uma div

Comment: Algumas referências:
https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker; 

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-datepicker;

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples;

Um exemplo:
http://jsfiddle.net/kGGCZ/3413/

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta, mas existem bibliotecas prontas para calendário, o materialize é um bom exemplo ou você pode pesquisar por datepicker. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker